# Unable to load distinct records via lookup in informatica

Tags: sql, oracle11g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

This is a very strange thing happening i dont know why. I have created a mapping that transforms the data via expression and loads the data into the target(file) based on lookup on the same target.

```
Source table

#CompanyName
Acne Lmtd
Acne Ltd
N/A
None 
Abc Ltd
Abc Ltd
X
```

Mapping

```
  Source
->Exp(trim..)
->Lookup(source.company_name
  = tgt.company_name)
   ReturnPort is CompId

  -> filter(ISNULL(CompId)) 
  -> Target 
    Compid (via sequence 
     gen) 
     CompName
```

The above mapping logic inserts duplicate companynames as well like in source 2 Abc Ltd records same is repeated in target as well. I dont know why. I have tried to debug as well the condition evaluates to true in filter that companyid is null even if the record is already inserted in target.

Also, i thought it might be the case of lookup cache i do enabled dynamic as well but same result. It should have worked like an sql query

```
select company_id
From lkptarget where 
company_name
In (select company_name 
 from 
Source)
```

Therefore, for Abc Ltd the filter condition should have result in false

```
  Isnull(company_id) false
```

But, this is getting true. How do I get unique records via lookup and without using distinct?

Note: lookup used is dynamic lookup already

[image]

Comment: You can always use an `Aggregator transform` and group by all the data you want to keep it distinct for. So if you group by all the columns only those who are distinct will come in the end.

Comment: Umm but i dont wanna use distinct in any way i guess i have mentioned above. What I did as above is applied a lookup on target for record if exists but on filtering it is showing as null meaning record doesnt exist even though it does

Comment: Any special reason why you dont want to use it?

Comment: This is a task given to me. Even though i would not require even aggregator too i can just use distinct in source qualifier but as i said its a task to implement it via lookup

Comment: Well then you can use group by clause to remove distinct.

Comment: You are not getting my point i have to refer target and discard already inserted records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was in fact a dynamic cache issue the newLookupRow gets assigned a value of 0 on duplicates so I have added the condition in filter as ISNULL(COMPANYID) AND NEWLOOKUPROW=1
and finally that did work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup transformation has not way to know what happens in further transformations in the mapping. It can't see results in the target itself, because the Lookup cache is loaded once at the beginning of the mapping using a separate connection to the database. Even if you disable caching (that would mean one query for each Lookup input row), data is not immediately committed (so not visible to other connections) when writing to the target.

That's the reason to use dynamic Lookup cache, which works by adding new lines to the Lookup cache. However in your case there is a catch : the `company_id` is created after the Lookup (it's the right place to do so), so it can't be added to the Lookup cache.

I think you could configure the Lookup so that :

- You activate the options `Dynamic Lookup Cache`, `Update Else Insert` and `Insert Else Update`
- You use the `company_name` to make comparison between source data and Lookup data
- You create a fake field `company_id` with value 0 before the Lookup and associate it to the corresponding Lookup field
- You check the checkbox `Disable in comparison` for the `company_id` field
- You can then use the predefined field `NewLookupRow` (it appears when you check the `Dynamic Lookup Cache` option) which should have a value of 1 for new rows or 2 for existing rows with updates (0 for identical rows)

The Lookup should now output `NewLookupRow = 1` for the first `Abc Ltd` and then `NewLookupRow = 0` for the second. The filter just after the Lookup should have a condition like `NewLookupRow = 1`.

For more details you can have a look at the Informatica documentation :
https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/developer-transformation-guide/dynamic-lookup-cache.html

Comment: I have already added that I have used dynamic lookup. Thats the basic difference dynamic lookup updates with data being updated static gets the same data during the whole first run.

Comment: Dynamic Lookup cache is only built once from target table and then from incoming data during mapping run, it can never know the new `company_id`s that the Sequence Generator creates. That's why you have to use the `NewLookupRow` predefined field in your filter, not the `company_id` field.

Comment: check the image above for reference

Comment: I have done it your explanation wasnt proper but detailed there is no dummy companyid etc is required and i just tried to debug the newlookup row and i din unable any of the update else insert etc as I had to reject all duplicates. Also there is nothing we need in explanation of "because the Lookup cache is loaded once at the beginning of the mapping using a separate connection to the database. Even if you disable caching (that would mean one query for each Lookup input row), data is not immediately committed (so not visible to other connections) when writing to the target.".

Comment: because its very simple and obvious the cache is static if only caching is enabled meaning that whatever cache which is collected remains in that particular run of lookup even if the referenced table gets updated it will take the data in cache whichever is available at the time of that lookups run